# How can I specify a generic class in the constructor of a class in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to inject a subclass into a class in the constructor using TypeScript.

Here's some pseudo-code that doesn't actually work that I think should demonstrate what I'm trying to do:

```
type GenericConstructor<T> = { new (): T; }

class MyClass {
  constructor(
    SubClass: GenericConstructor
  ) {
     this.subclass = new SubClass();
  }
}

class MySubClass1 {}

class MySubClass2 {}

const withSubClass1 = new MyClass(MySubClass1);
const withSubClass2 = new MyClass(MySubClass2);
```

The problem is that TypeScript won't allow me to specify a generic parameter on a constructor (I suspect I'm just doing something wrongly).

What I'm trying to achieve is a class (`MyClass`) that can accept a generic child class that fulfils a certain interface of its own.  I wonder if the correct way of doing this might be to specify an interface instead but I'm not entirely sure how.

Thanks for all help!

Comment: You should make `MyClass` itself generic, like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hB2EBOBLAxgYQPbwM7CQFc1gskAeAFQD4oBeKAbykQHcAKASgC4pKBuKAF8AsAChxaADYBDXLigBZEBlnyqtRuKhRchAEbS5uXgO1Q0OfERJl25nQGUDq47ziJUmKwWKkKNOacTA5QwAAWKLgAdHqGagoMbFDO+q7yXPzmomI5kglKIKnpuACMTFAy9FAARDXC4vnGhcUJAEwV+tV1DRJilnjAUKwoEa3G5UkQrIUl7Mrj8qWcWf0+w6Phi7gdUzPKcwsu7StAA).  If that meets your needs I'll write up an answer; otherwise please edit the question to clarify.  Good luck!

Comment: Checking it out... thanks a lot!

Comment: That works nicely although I've now run into another problem ;).  Typical!  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can't make a `constructor` method declaration generic, because it would [collide](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10860#issuecomment-246456721) with the class itself possibly being generic.  What I mean is, if you had this:

```
class Foo<T> { constructor<U>() { } } // error, but imagine no error
```

Then it wouldn't be clear when calling `new Foo<X>()` whether `X` specifies `T` or `U` or neither or both.  There are ways of working around this, but luckily it doesn't look like this is what you need.

---

Rather, I presume you want `withSubClass1` to remember that its `subclass` property is of type `SubClass1`, while `withSubClass2` should remember that its `subclass` property is of type `SubClass2`.  In that case, `MyClass` should itself be generic in the type of the `subclass` property, and we'll let the compiler infer this type from the constructor parameter:

```
class MyClass<T> {
  subclass: T;
  constructor(subclassCtor: new () => T) {
    this.subclass = new subclassCtor();
  }
}
```

And when we construct instances of it, this is what we get:

```
const withSubClass1 = new MyClass(MySubClass1);
// const withSubClass1: MyClass<MySubClass1>

const withSubClass2 = new MyClass(MySubClass2);
// const withSubClass2: MyClass<MySubClass2>
```

Assuming `MySubClass1` and `MySubClass2` have some structure to them (and are structurally distinct from each other; [this is actually important](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely) even for example code):

```
class MySubClass1 { a = "" }
class MySubClass2 { b = "" }
```

Then your instances of `MyClass` will see that structure in their `subclass` property:

```
withSubClass1.subclass.a.toUpperCase(); // okay
withSubClass2.subclass.b.toLowerCase(); // okay
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28A8AVAfNA3tY8B2EALgE4Cuwh8xSAqmgBQCUW0Avm9APSfQCmxxKgEJoAWABQE0JBgBZAJ4BhcFFQZME6NAikARtKgAuaCgDcmnPiJkKVejv0qIiysWN5eAd2hNoAXgwUZg1xLS1CAAsASwgAOgcDGD9oD28Epxc7RnNQtglWCSknaAUAZT1lGQBGFjB-aAAiBrzJcUSS+XLdSqgAJhZdeqaWqStCaE8oyK6eiBrk1I7Z+jKKpyrsiW5LAnHJ6bXq4wVZpFXu9bRCtrGJqYiZp36FryWnFc7Dvs3xbdxdu4HC4yXrHJROM6fYF9K6tfYPL5zeJ6RKxMCxSg0AAOWP4ikgvCYpi4PHgAGswPIJPDHiDkY4ZLFdBj4AAZeCePEEokk6DkynXIA)

Comment: Thanks very much, especially for the extra tip on the addition of private props to empty classes - I didn't know!